# Application of Lebesgue Dominated Convergence.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, show that $$ \int_{-x}^{x} f(t) dt \to \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} f(t) dt$$ as $x \to \infty$.

$\textbf{My Attempt:}$ We can rewrite, $$ \int_{-x}^{x} f(t) dt = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(t) \chi_{(-x,x)} (t) dt$$

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $x_n \to \infty$ as $n \to infty$, then $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \int_{-x}^x f(t) dt = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(t) \chi_{ (-x_n, x_n)} (t) dt$$ Let $g_n(x) = f(t) \chi_{(-x_n, x_n)}$, then $|g_n(x)|=|f(t) \chi_{(-x_n,x_n)}| \le |f(t)| \in L^1$. Also, as $n \to \infty$, we have $g_n(x) \to f(t) \chi_{(-\infty, \infty)}$. Then by Lebesgue dominated convergence we have,

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \int_{- x}^{x} f(t) dt = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \lim_{n \to \infty} f(t) \chi_{(-x_n, x_n)} (t) dt = \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} f(t) dt$$

Are there any errors in this proof?

Comment: Aside from the likely typo $g_n(x) = f(t)\chi_{(-x_n,x_n)}$, the proof looks correct. The important thing is that you are dominating the *integrand*, not the *integral*. Indeed, you have a uniform bound $|f(t)| \geq |g_n(t)|$ which holds for all $n$, and $\chi_{(-x_n,x_n)}(t) \rightarrow t$ pointwise, so you are good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is fine.

As an alternative, you can also (writing $f = f_+ - f_-$) assume that $f\ge 0$; and then apply the monotonic convergence theorem.